# Start Roman numerals after ToC using memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, front-matter, roman-numerals

I have the following template for a book using memoir:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Nothing}
\chapter*{Nothing}

\clearpage


\begin{KeepFromToc}
  \tableofcontents
\end{KeepFromToc}

\chapter{0-One}
\lipsum[2-10]

\chapter{1-Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-10]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

The first entry in the ToC is "0-One", which starts at page V in the above MWE. However, I'd like for the Roman numerals to start right after the ToC with I, i.e., "0-One" should be I and not V.

Is it possible to do this using memoir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a second `\frontmatter` command, which will reset the numbering.  You also don't need the `KeepFromToc` for the `\tableofcontents`; just use `\tableofcontents*`.  To remove the numbering entirely from the initial pages, you can alias the `chapter` pagestyle to empty, and then restore it after the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
\chapter*{Nothing}
\chapter*{Nothing}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents*
\clearpage
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}
\frontmatter
\chapter{0-One}
\lipsum[2-10]

\chapter{1-Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-10]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Nice, thanks. The first 4 pages have numbers i-iv though, after which it resets to i. Is there a way to remove the numbers for the first 4 pages entirely?

Comment: @BillyJean - Use `\pagestyle{empty}` for the page(s) for which page numbers shouldn't be printed (along with `\thispagestyle{empty}` on pages with chapter-level headers). Use `\pagestyle{plain}` to restart "normal" page numbering.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I tried that, but I don't see any effect of `\pagestyle{empty}`. I am placing it both before and after the first `frontmatter`

Comment: @BillyJean - Did you insert `\pagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\frontmatter`, along with `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after each and every `\chapter*` and `\chapter` directive?

Comment: @Mico That did the trick

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear from your question that that's what you wanted.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Mico There's a simpler way to do this. (See edit.)

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thanks. That's indeed much neater. In the meantime, it occurred to me that the OP may (or may not...) prefer the `headings` page style to the `plain` page style.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `\pagenumbering{alph}` for the part before `\frontmatter` (you'll know why when you'll add `hyperref`). With a group, the changes made to the page styles will be forgotten as soon as the group ends.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}

\begingroup
\pagestyle{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\chapter*{Nothing}
\chapter*{Nothing}

\endgroup

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{headings}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{0-One}
\lipsum[2-10]

\chapter{1-Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[2-10]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

With page numbering `roman` or `arabic`, `hyperref` would be in trouble, because more than one page would get the same internal reference, which is built using the page number. Any other page numbering model will do, so also `Roman` or `Alph` would do. Alternatively, one might renew the definition of `\thepage` adding a prefix to the arabic number.

The group, that's not generally advisable for normal chapters, will keep the redefinitions of the page style local. In these “prechapters” you'll probably have material pertaining to the bureaucracy of your institution, such as committee names and declarations, so no cross-reference or other things that could impact on memory. At `\endgroup`, the redefinitions will vanish, thus not requiring to reinstate the normal page styles that you may define at will in the document preamble.

Comment: Damn you `hyperref`. :)

Comment: Although it might be helpful to explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @AlanMunn Added